# How to find the extreme corner point in image ？

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

[image: source image1]
[image: source image2]

[image: destination image1]
[image: destination image2]

Form the source images above ( source image1、image2), I wanna find the extreme corner point and get the points like  destination image1、image2  what I draw the red circle point.

Actually I investigate the Harris、Shi Tomasi Algorithm， but they are not so extreme.

Actually I have tried **goodFeaturesTotrack** using java code, likes:

```
goodFeaturesToTrack(basedImg,corners,10,0.2,10,maskMat,3,false,0.04);  for (int j=0;j<cornerArray.length;j++){
                Point curP = cornerArray[j];
                Imgproc.circle(retImg,curP,3,new Scalar(255,0,0),-1);
            }
```

the result image is following:

[image: magnify to find blue corner point]

Although it could find some blue characteristic point, but not so extremely as what I showed the destination image1、image2.

So do you have some good idea to find the corner point which are special character ?

Comment: From my point of view, your problem/task is not sufficiently defined. How do you describe an "extreme corner point"? Stack Overflow is for actual coding questions, not to outsource the underlying problem solving. Please provide a proper description of the "extreme corner points", and show any approach (and code), you've tried so far.

Comment: From my destination image1、image2， you could see the corner point what I draw. It is the example of  extreme corner point

Comment: I would start with [`approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` for corner detection. The function takes four parameters

```
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance)
```

- `image` - Input 8-bit or floating-point 32-bit grayscale single-channel image
- `maxCorners` - Maximum number of corners to return
- `qualityLevel` - Minimum accepted quality level of corners between 0-1. All corners below quality level are rejected
- `minDistance` - Minimum possible Euclidean distance between corners

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,10,0.2,20)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(image,(x,y),5,(36,255,12),-1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I have tried the goodFeaturesToTrack, but it is not so extreme.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by extreme?

Comment: find the corner point what I draw on the destination image1、image2 .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) could give you what you are looking for, if you treat the binary image pixels as a collection of points to enclose.

Example from their docs:

[image: points]

[image: enclosed]