# open cv to calculate number of bends in PCB layout trace

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

[image: Serpentine pcb track]

How can i use openCV to calculate number of serpentine bends in pcb layout diagram as shown. Here the required output i.e. number of bends is 9. I'm using this script as reference but couldn't find correct output [Count the number of rectangles in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569457/count-the-number-of-rectangles-in-an-image)

Comment: Count the number of corners and divide appropriately. See cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541

Comment: Approach #1: Count number of corners in the image with [`cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d8c/tutorial_py_shi_tomasi.html), the number of bends = (number of corners)/2 - 1. Approach #2: With the assumption that the image is just the PCB layout trace with no other lines, you can create a vertical shaped kernel to filter out vertical lines then count the number of contours. The answer will be # of contours - 1